# How to access the Redfish(https://xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/redfish/v1 ) in Openbmc

Tags: openbmc

I am newbiee to openbmc and Redfish.

I wanted to view the https://xxx.xxx.xxx(or localhost):8000/redfish/v1" content in webbrowser after i build the OpenBMC. Please guide to connect the dots to view the redfish/v1 content in the browser after building/compiling the OpenBMC.

Here are the steps used to compile the openBMC:

here are the steps i have followed:

1. Clone OpenBMC project : git clone https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc.git in the server machine
2. Compile using the following command: TEMPLATECONF=meta-phosphor/conf  . openbmc-env
3. modify the following files:
   #build vi conf/local.conf   (modify the  line "-MACHINE??=qemuarm" " to    "-MACHINE??=raspberrypi3-64" "
   #build vi conf/bblayer.conf (add the following line "/home/khader/openbmc/meta-raspberrypi "  to the line  above /home/khader/openbmc/metaphosphor "
4. #build   bitbake obmc-phosphor-image

The above steps I have used to build an Openbmc project.

Can you help me what further steps should i need to do so that i can view the /redfish/v1/  content in the webbrowser.

Note:- I am compiling the openbmc code in the local machine and wants to use the same as localhost server to view the /redfish/v1 contents in the webbrowser.

Any help /guidelines on this will really help me alot.
Appreciate all your help.

Thanks & Regards,
khader

Comment: When you started QEMU, did you forward the appropriate port? Did you verify a basic curl of the redfish api works (i.e. curl -b cjar -k https://${localhost:qemu_port}/redfish/v1). https://github.com/openbmc/docs/blob/master/development/dev-environment.md#download-and-start-qemu-session may be useful to you.

Comment: Check https://github.com/openbmc/docs/blob/master/cheatsheet.md#using-qemu to see how to use qemu with port mapping. And then you could access redfish with 2443 port.